# Should I put a break after a throw in a switch statement?

Tags: c++

Should I put a break after a throw in a switch case statement?

Option 1:

```
switch(value){
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                throw APException();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Option 2:

```
switch(value){
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                throw APException();
            default:
                break;
        }
```

I think if I put a break after the throw it will give me a compile error. So, considering the Option 2, is this an acceptable solution?

Comment: `break;` is unreachable and it may indeed produce warning for unreachable code.

Comment: No `break` after `throw` or `return`.

Comment: If your doing something like this use the `[[fallthrough]]` attribute

Comment: @Eljay Of course. I mean before the `throw` you should put it to the case label.

Answer (score 3):

A [`throw` expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> ... transfers control to the exception handler with the matching type for which the compound statement or member initializer list that follows the keyword try was most recently entered and not exited by this thread of execution.

Therefore, the `break` is unreachable after the `throw`, making the `break` unnecessary (and, in fact, it produces a warning for some compilers), and so it should be omitted.